# Adding new dimensions to image in c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I need to implement the function below in c++ that takes image in the form [width,height,3] and rescales it to [1,32,32,1] this is an example in python

```
def rescale(img_path):
 img = cv2.imread(img_path)
 img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 input_data = img_gray[ ..., tf.newaxis]
 input_data  =tf.image.resize(input_data, [32,32])
 input_data = input_data[ tf.newaxis,...]
 input_data = np.array(input_data, dtype=np.float32)
 return input_data
```

how can I do the same in c++ ??

Comment: I'm not sure what output you want because i dont understand what the tensor flow code is doing. By [32,32,1] we mean 1-channel 32x32 gray scale. But what does adding another dimension of size 1 to the left mean. Wouldnt [1, 32, 32, 1] be the same thing as [32,32,1]? Like if it were [2,32,32,1] then you would have two planes but it is one so you don't...

Comment: @jwezorek I have built a  tflite model that  takes input in the form [batch_size,width,height,channels] so while inference I need batch_size =1